# TypeScript union with required discriminant string

Tags: typescript, discriminated-union, union-types

The problem i'm trying to solve is making sure that type of the parameter passed to the `doSomething` function is a union, which has `__typename: 'GenericError'` option.

This is extract form the functionality i'm working:

```
type TypeNamedResponse = {
  __typename: string;
};

type GenericError = {
  message: string;
};


type ErrorTypeResponse = {
  __typename: 'GenericError';
} & GenericError;


type ResponseType<TResponse extends TypeNamedResponse> =
  | WithoutError<TResponse>
  | ErrorTypeResponse;

type WithoutError<TResponse> = Exclude<
  TResponse,
  ErrorTypeResponse
>;


function doSomething<TResponse extends TypeNamedResponse> (response: ResponseType<TResponse>) : WithoutError<TResponse> {
 // this function performs some narrowing on the union type,
 // if '__typename !== 'GenericError` it eventually returns original response 
// with correctly inferred type.
}
```

These are possible arguments that may be passed to `doSomething` function. I do not control these.

```
type ValidArgument = {
  __typnename: 'GenericError'; <-- this is required
  message: string;
} | {
  __typename:'SomeType'; 
  someProp: string;
}

type InvalidArgument = {
  __typename: string; 
  someProp: string;
}

const valid:ValidArgument = {
  __typename: 'SomeType',
  someProp: 'SomeProp'
}

const valid:InvalidArgument = {
  __typename: 'SomeType',
  someProp: 'SomeProp'
}
```

And that's what I'm trying to achieve:

```
doSomething(valid) // OK
doSomething(invalid) // compiler error
```

I want to make sure that consumer of `doSomething` is passing the data matching the correct type.

Answer (score 0):

There is a typo in your interface

```
type ValidArgument = {
  __typnename: 'GenericError';
  message: string;
} | {
  __typename:'SomeType;  <--- this needs to close the quotation otherwise `__typename` would be the string "SomeType;" (with a semicolon)
  someProp: string;
}
```

See [TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=54&pc=39#code/C4TwDgpgBAKuEDkCGBbCATAShAzmA9gHY7QC8UA3gFBRQD6dokhqEAXFDsAE4CWhAcwDcVAL4iqTaAHEIhCHwDGAUW7d83KOWq00OHEgHtOPfsLETJ8KKvXc4kbHiIktlGvUbwWaDgHJZeSVbDT8RUSgAMihAhV4VNQ1LKSgnAmIIBwgAHhg0l2gIAA9gOXQcWHhkNCxcdJIAPi0PAB8oAHVeYAALfABXYBDuXPyMhtabRPt4UZIJFM6e-sGpkbqCpvJlIsUAGz70HI889YyAGg8hrNmIKgbLADM%20wkVgXiIodHwAZXw0HrMa2cGSgxVKhHKlUg1QwNyaAApuKcSBwblkgfUIA0AJRQDiLXoDIYYjbuKAAenJUABFSeLzeH0g3AeGhQFRwf2gLESAHczFAPj1oM93oRqfAzlAAEYDUEANzkwD6SF2uxAUCRSu4xAFfAE-BVGuR0F4DygXSgPKQOEIfmAUCQMTkcQSdgF8jEVCskCgADUVbx0ABBbgCPpoQj27QeBhMeQ%20YwBZ3BKZhKAePQGIwcLh8QThKBtHSeKQJth%20X5oLJhDwctAABXUYBzpnznu90AAkoQ5QHg6Hw4q3MXY95WC288J07Q6xBG-hmyZJ%20EvYoXPbe7tAxx-Vv%202GI1GySWx74oBXOdWLjPOfPFxeG02-O218R7fxN9vu5-94PI8OYy8Zhx3PStMngPxr04W8m38MC72fUQvSoL4wIBQR4R-XFKSgAB5ABpFCfk5dCBHhD8%202wqk1xQMBeF2BRQSmIA)